# How markup arbitrary key-value-pairs of my products with Schema.org and/or GoodRelations with Microdata?

Tags: key-value, microdata, schema.org

After search a lot I found the following:

- https://schema.org/Property
- http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/Documentation/Product_features

to markup arbitrary key-value-pairs on my Microdata.

I have products following https://schema.org/Product and a lot of features from each one that vary from one type to another.

The GoodRelations link tell to do it:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemid="#model">
    <span itemprop="name">ACME Electric Anvil</span>...
    <div itemprop="feature" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProductFeature">
        <span itemprop="propertyName">Safety belt</span>:
        <span itemprop="propertyValue">yes</span>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="feature" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProductFeature">
        <span itemprop="propertyName">Weight</span>:
        <span itemprop="propertyValue">2.25</span>
        <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="KGM">kg
    </div>  
</div>
```

but Schema.org tell about https://schema.org/Property with `domainIncludes` and `rangeIncludes` without any example or documentation, only tell its equivalent to `rdf:Property`.

---

Is possible see it dont validate on richsnippets validator here:

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004f521a6b9b2a553602e5a1d723fb5

---

How to markup key-value-pairs of my product with Schema.org and/or GoodRelations with Microdata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** In the meantime, there exists an official, fully elaborated proposal for exactly this kind of feature in schema.org:

https://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/PropertyValuePairs

See the examples in the W3C wiki for details.

The same mechanism will soon be available from the GoodRelations namespace.

Note that it does not yet work in live Web sites - you will have to wait for the proposal to be added to schema.org.

There is not yet an official statement on whether and when the extension proposal will be considered, but there are quite some use-cases for this, which is why I am optimistic about it.

Best wishes

Martin

Comment: A live demo of the proposal in practice is here: http://sdo-property-value.appspot.com/PropertyValue

Comment: There are now also lots of examples of how to use this proposed feature, see http://sdo-property-value-and-cars.appspot.com/PropertyValue (scroll down to the end of page for the examples in Microdata, RDFa, and JSON-D).

Answer (score 0):

we have exact same problem like your and find solution. **additionalProperty**

```
  <div itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
      <span itemprop="name">Approx. Weight</span>
      <span itemprop="value">450</span>
      <span itemprop="unitText">g</span>
  </div>
```

[more details](http://schema.org/additionalProperty)